# как на С++ реализовать что то подобное?

Tags: python, c++

на python вот такой код,

```
quares = []
    for x in range(5):
        squares.append(lambda: x**2)
```

соответственно  он будет возвращать 16 всегда

```
squares[2]()
```

но мне захотелось такое сделать на плюсах, как это можно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почти так же:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::vector<std::function<int()>> squares;
    int x;
    
    for (x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
        squares.push_back([&x](){return x * x;});
    }

    std::cout << squares[2]() << '\n';
}
```

Однако, в отличие от питона, будет возвращать `5**2`, потому что цикл останавливается на `5`, а не на `4`. Если надо чтобы именно на `4`, то заведите отдельную переменную для количества итераций либо цикл до предпоследнего + дополнительная итерация и т.п..

Comment: За что минусы, кто-нибудь пояснит?

Comment: karmik , спасибо, то что я и хотел.  а если x объявить в цикле, почему потом в не тела цикла  все работает?

Comment: @Venot определение `x` вынесите вне цикла, в питоне переменная из цикла видна во всей внешней функции, а в C++ нет, поэтому при таком коде вызов `squares[2]()` вне цикла ведёт к UB.

Comment: понятно,спасибо. а я протестил у меня все работает. а теперь понял это все таки UB